# Tesseract OCR integration to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, tesseract, leptonica

There is a question same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582505/compile-tesseract-for-visual-studio-2013). But the solution is not there. I use windows8, visual studio 2013. My machine is 64bit. I try to integrate tesseract ocr to vs2013. I install leptonica from [here](http://code.google.com/p/leptonica/downloads/detail?name=leptonica-1.68-win32-lib-include-dirs.zip&can=2&q=) and tesseract from [here](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-3.02.eng.tar.gz&can=2&q=).

I did below steps :

1. Project solutions -> C++ -> General

   ```
   C:\Tesseract-OCR\include
   C:\Tesseract-OCR\include\tesseract
   C:\Tesseract-OCR\include\leptonica
   ```
2. Linker-> General -> Additional Library Directories

   C:\Tesseract-OCR\lib
3. Linker->Input ->Additional Dependencies

   `libtesseract302.lib
   liblept168.lib`
4. Restart vs2013

I try below line in main function `tesseract::TessBaseAPI api;'. When I run these code, I get an error.

Error message :

```
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl tesseract::TessBaseAPI::~TessBaseAPI(void)" (??1TessBaseAPI@tesseract@@UEAA@XZ)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few small things I figured out that make sample code compile

1.more include directories are required. My directories don't exactly match OP.

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\include
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\include\leptonica
- all irectories of form C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract-ocr[subdirectory]

  2. At top of main file paste the following line

  #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS  //prevents a deprecation error from the tesserect API

  3. The required file libtesseract302.lib does not come with the windows installer. You must download and unzip tesseract-3.02.02-win32-lib-include-dirs.zip. Then copy all the files into C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\lib

Comment: another small thing C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\lib has to be added to the path for the program to run after it is compiled